# Incorporating experimental uncertainty into prediction interval

Tags: r, uncertainty

I have the following data

```
Temperature,values
175.5 ,-22.35
148.6 ,-21.55
125.2 ,-20.62
99.8  ,-19.66
75.9  ,-18.74
50.6  ,-17.56
174.6 ,-22.26
152.1 ,-21.46
100.5 ,-19.30
152.2 ,-22.00
124.7 ,-20.48
175.1 ,-22.86
125.0 ,-20.96
74.7  ,-18.66
50.6  ,-17.72
227.2 ,-25.18
174.4 ,-22.48
199.4 ,-23.87
99.2  ,-19.79
50.0  ,-17.81
124.2 ,-20.53
247.5 ,-27.13
176.5 ,-22.45
228.2 ,-25.66
252.5 ,-26.44
180.7 ,-23.15
139.4 ,-21.46
221.2 ,-25.22
```

The values come with an experimental uncertainty of +/- 0.3. I can currently examine my prediction intervals as such;

```
df <- data
fm1 <- lm(values ~ 1 + Temperature + I(Temperature ^-1), data=df)

pred_int <- data.frame( Temperature = seq(0, 300, by=1))
predict(fm1,newdata=pred_int,interval="prediction")
```

I'm wondering how best to incorporate the experimental uncertainty into the prediction intervals? I've seen some suggesting modeling as noise etc but I'm not too sure what the best way forward is.

EDIT

[image]

Comment: How do you want to "incorporate" the uncertainty? The regression estimates as well as the prediction intervals are *conditional* on the *observed* values of the explanatory variable, so its uncertainty should play no role.

Comment: @whuber I'm not too sure how to incorporate the uncertainty but I'd like to if possible. Say if the experimental error had a value of 1 or 2, which would be extremely large, I'd think there would be a way to reflect this in the confidence intervals? 
I've added a graph with the data points and the +/- 0.3 experimental error uncertainty. To my eye the confidence look pretty tight around the regression.

Comment: The problem is that so far the uncertainty in the explanatory variable plays no role in the prediction.  That suggests your prediction intervals differ from what they are generally understood to be, implying you must provide a clear explanation of your objective.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for you response. I think I updated my comment as you posted. 

'The problem is that so far the uncertainty in the explanatory variable plays no role in the prediction.' - Is this possible to do? Should I change from a linear model or add the uncertainty into the model by some method?

Comment: You haven't yet articulated a question in which that uncertainty plays any role, so it cannot be answered.

Comment: Hi @whuber I feel like I've tried to explain my problem as best as I can but I'll try and rephrase.

Are you saying that I cannot incorporate my understandings of the experimental uncertainties (which are due to the different machines having different tolerances etc) which are attached to each datapoint into producing the confidence intervals/prediction intervals.

 At the moment this uncertainty data plays no role in my statistical analysis, I only use the measured values and so the confidence intervals reflect the scatter present in the data.

Comment: @whuber I'm wondering wether I can reflect both the scatter around the regression and also the inherent uncertainty in the data to produce the confidence intervals/prediction intervals?

Comment: It comes down to what you're trying to predict from what. Your question reads like you wish to predict `values` from a `temperature`. A regression model considers how `values` depends on the *observed* value of `temperature`. A regression prediction interval therefore tells you where to expect `values` to lie, given the *observed* value of `temperature`. The observed value is whatever it is: there's no uncertainty to it. It's pointless to predict `values` from the *true* `temperature`, because you will never know that.

Comment: Now if your question concerns how to incorporate the measurement uncertainty of `values`, note that this is already estimated by the regression model because it's inherent in all the observations.

Comment: Now if your question concerns how to incorporate the measurement uncertainty of values, note that this is already estimated by the regression model because it's inherent in all the observations. - Yes this is my question. In my situation I know what the experimental uncertainties are of all of the different processes which combine to give me an uncertainty of 0.3 for each measurement contained in `values`. So just checking -> this prior known uncertainty of 0.3 is redundant and not usable in a linear model or any regression model for that matter? It is calculated by the model each time.

Comment: Could you clarify how it is calculated by the model?

Comment: When I said  'It is calculated by the model each time' I was referring to your previous comment ' if your question concerns how to incorporate the measurement uncertainty of values, note that this is already estimated by the regression model because it's inherent in all the observations.' 

From your comment I interpreted that you were saying the measurement uncertainty is essentially calculated by the model and as such the experimental (measurement) uncertainty I have previously calculated, which is a combination of the tolerances of machines  and procedures etc, of +/- 0.3 is redundant...

Comment: ...and cannot be used in a regression model. I interpreted you were saying this value of measurement uncertainty (+/- 0.3) is inherent to the data and already is estimated by the linear model. The experimental (measurement) uncertainty of 0.3 which is associated with `values` (i.e. the first data point is -22.35 +/-0.3) cannot be included in a model.

Comment: It's not calculated by the model, but is incorporated in it.  You are comparing a model of the form $Y = f(x) + \varepsilon$ to one of the form $Y = f(x) + \delta + \gamma.$ In the first, $\varepsilon$ is a random variable modeling all deviation between $Y$ and $f(x).$ In the second, $\delta$ plays that role and $\gamma$ is the measurement error. Obviously $\varepsilon=\delta+\gamma$ and the model cannot split $\varepsilon$ into components. Its estimate of the error variance is the sum of the variances of $\delta$ and $\gamma,$ but it does *not* separately estimate those variances.

Comment: Okay thanks very much for your time and comments @whuber. Thats greatly appreciated. I hope this thread helps someone else :)

Comment: This might be interesting and may open a door in some extent http://rforbiostatistics.colmanstatistics.be/2018/06/13/comparing-methods-using-a-prediction-interval/ Please have a look